# Get Values of Dropdown Upon Select of First Dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, variables

```
        <select style="width:300px;" id="n" name="userListingCategory">
              <option  disabled="disabled">Category...</option>
                  <?php while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                  {echo "<option value=". $row['catID'] . ">" .$row['catName']."</option>";}
                unset($sth2);
                ?>

            </select> 
             <select style="width:340px;" id="n" name="userListingSCategory">
           <option  disabled="disabled">Sub-Category...</option>
               <?php while($row = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                  {echo "<option value=". $row['scatID'] . ">" .$row['scatName']."</option>";}
                unset($sth3);
             ?>
```

This makes two dropdown lists with values.

Upon clicking a `userListingCategory`, I want the following SQL to run to get the associated  subcategories (`userListingSCategory`):

```
SELECT scatID, scatName
FROM Category C, SubCategory SC
WHERE $valueOfFirstSelected = SC.catID;
```

Which will in essence, get the SubCategory ID and Name associated with the ID of the Category originally selected (hence: `$valueOfFirstSelected`)

Anyone? Ajax or jQuery or Php would be most beneficial.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about how javascript, php, and mysql interact with each other. You might want to look at some tutorials of using javascript and jquery with ajax and then using mysql with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**your file:**

```
<select id="select_one" onchange="FillSelectTwo(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    ...
</select> 
<select id="select_two">
    ...
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function FillSelectTwo(id) {
    $('#select_two').find('option').remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_fill_select_two.php?id='+id,
                    dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#select_two').append(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**ajax_fill_select_two.php:**

```
<!-- of course you need to generate it using $_GET['id'] -->
<option value="0">text</option>
<option value="1">text</option>
<option value="2">text</option>
<option value="3">text</option>
```

the best solution is send `JSON` data thru ajax response and add `option` fields to select_two via javascript

Comment: But these values ARENT in the url, how can I use get here?

Comment: what values? How it works: when user change selected option in first dropbox you make ajax request for options in second dropbox.

Comment: I am now getting nothing in the second dropdown. Why isn't the NEW CODE section working?

Comment: The Ajax doesnt seem to be pulling anything?

Comment: Ok, it's my fold - just add `dataType` to ajax parameters - https://gist.github.com/1299951. Working example avaiable [here](https://gist.github.com/1299954)

Comment: Peter, please see: https://gist.github.com/1300009 . It still seems like its doing something when i click the first dropdown, since it clears the `disabled` option in the `select`, but then brings up nothing. Thoughts??

Comment: I'd really appreciate you helping me further, its really beneficial. : Jay

Comment: works fine for me http://host9.info/Jay/test.html maybe install firebug and debug javascript and ajax response to find what's wrong

Comment: Yeah, it does work on there, but the values within the <option> </option> aren't different from the (3) different subcategory options

Comment: The subcategory options are grabbed from the `SubCategory` table, based on the value of the `Category` chosen. So the `SQL` might look like: `SELECT scatID, scatName
FROM Category C, SubCategory SC
WHERE $valueOfFirstSelected = SC.catID;`

Comment: Does that make sense what I'm trying to do? Basically, call that SQL Query above upon a `Category` being selected and throw the results into the `SubCategory` dropdown.

Comment: Please make another question @ stack overflow. As you see my answer is enough for current question. And sorry for my English :)